# How do I run curl command within Docker yml file?

Tags: windows, docker, curl

I have 2 docker containers that are run in docker-compose, but are no longer talking to one another (connection refused error, when trying to perform a GraphQL mutation). To debug this I want to replace one of them with a simple curl command.

Original yml:

```
services:
  backend_container:
    container_name: backend_container
    image: backend_container:latest
    command: parm1 parm2
    volumes:
      - /c/path_to_data:/data/in
    ports:
      - 19777:19777
    depends_on:
      - ui_container
    
  ui_container:
    container_name: ui_container
    image: ui_container:latest
    ports:
      - 801:8080
```

proposed yml:

```
services: 
  test_ui:
    container_name: test_ui
    volumes:
      - /c/path_to_data:/data/in
         depends_on:
      - ui_container
    command: 
    bash -c 'curl -X POST --data-binary \"@/data/in/my_query.txt\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H 
       \"Accept: application/json\" 
       http://ui_container:8080/graphql'

  ui_container:
    same as before
```

I am new docker so I have a couple of questions:

1. Does this make sense to do this (have a curl as a service)?
2. I have tried to escape the quotes and colon in the curl command but I get an error `ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here` pointing at the colon after 'Accept'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Does it make sense to [...] have curl as a service?

Not really.  For very short-term debugging, possibly, but in general a single command that will exit immediately doesn't make a good Compose service.  A better approach might be to [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) a similarly-configured container with an alternate command:

```
docker-compose run backend_container \
  curl --data-binary @/data/in/my_query.txt ...
```

> 2. I have tried to escape the quotes and colon in the curl command....

YAML has several ways to quote and escape strings.  Here I would probably use a [folded block scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251): you can write a string across multiple lines, and it will get collapsed down into one line separated by spaces.  This particular call does not need a `sh -c` wrapper (you'd only need it if you had shell redirections or environment variable references) and skipping that also saves a level of quoting.

```yaml
command: >-
  curl
  -X POST
  --data-binary @/data/in/my_query.txt
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -H "Accept: application/json"
   http://ui_container:8080/graphql
```

Another good approach here is to use the list form of `command`.  Again, you can't use shell constructs here, but you can (and have to) explicitly specify what "words" are.

```
command:
  - curl
  - -X
  - POST
  - --data-binary
  - @/data/in/my_query.txt
  - -H
  - "Content-Type: application/json" # <-- YAML string quoting
  - -H
  - "Accept: application/json"
  - "http://ui_container:8080/graphql"
```

Comment: Thank you , very helpful. Should `docker-compose run backend_container \
  curl --data-binary @/data/in/my_query.txt ...' be 'docker-compose run ui_container...`? Or do I need to run all the other containers separately?  Also how do I give the container parms if I use `run`?

Comment: [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) uses most of the settings from the `docker-compose.yml` file (it overrides `command:` and intentionally ignores `ports:`).  I'm guessing you want to test the client call from the other container, which is why I used that container name.